# Resize screen during video playng

Tags: javascript, video.js, video-player

How I can resize video player during video playing, resize screen for 10 second and then return to initial dimension.

For example initial dimension 640 x 480 every 30 second player resize automatic to 440 x 280 for 10 second and then return to 640 x 480.

Is possible with video.js?

Answer (score 1):

As per video.js documentation [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/guides/options.md) :

> The Video.js embed code is simply an HTML5 video tag, so for many of
>   the options you can use the standard tag attributes to set the
>   options.

Because video.js uses the standard HTML tag you can create an addEventListener based on clicking play as per the HTML5  element's standards [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-video-element).

So with this understanding we can move forward to build the event listener. Tt would look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener('play', stretch, false);

function stretch() {
        this.removeEventListener('play', stretch, false);
        document.getElementById("stretchMe").style.width="800px";

}
```